# Is there any "real life" episodes in Log Horizon?

Tags: log-horizon

I was wondering if there is any episode in Log Horizon set outside the game, similar to some episodes found in Sword Art Online, or is it entirely set inside the game?

Answer (score 1):

Log Horizon has no episodes that are completely outside the game.
There are very short scenes on the subject every now and then, but a complete episode would require that they get back to their world, which, hasn't happened in season 1 or 2.

Comment: Nah. Every short scene so far has been a flashback and they could do an entire _LOST_ style episode like that, they just haven't and aren't likely to. The focus is on the game world and so far the flashbacks only appear to illustrate points as adventurers explain something about who they are as a person.